# How to enable/disable redmine plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have a situation in my redmine installation that I want to enable a plugin including its all features for a couple days in the month. Is there a way to enable/disable a redmine plugin via configurations without adding/removing it from source?

Answer (score 1):

You could comment the file init.rb inside the plugin, that's where the plugin initializes